# Reference many buttons in a short method

Tags: android, button

I'm designing a keyboard for Android.
I just learned this neat way of defining my buttons in the onCreate method by implementing the View.OnTouchListener in my MainActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    defineButtons();


    keyC.setOnTouchListener(this);
//etc..

}
```

and then:

```
    private void defineButtons()
{

    keyC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c);
//etc..
}
```

Then i would define what happens when the buttons are touched by this method:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motion)
{
    int note = 0;

    switch(view.getId())
    {

    case R.id.c:    /** Note C*/
    {
        note = 60 + transposeOctave;
        motionTracker(view, motion, note);
    }
    break;
//etc...
}
```

This last method has to be repeated for every button separately, which seems kind of ugly. 
Can I use the Id to return a numerical value to modify my note value maybe?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your keys defined in XML? If so, I would simply add a `tag` to each one with the proper numeric value, like so:

```
android:tag="1"
```

Then, in your code, you can simply do this:

```
int note = 0;
int tagValue = 0;

//Tags in XML are always strings
String tag = (String)view.getTag();

//Parse it to an integer
tagValue = Integer.parseInt(tag);

note = tagValue + transposeOctave;
motionTracker(view, motion, note);
```

Comment: Oh thanks alot, that's simple! I've really been searching through the android:-tags, must have missed that one. :)

Comment: Sure thing! One detail tho, why do you have to typecast to String if it is already stored as a String in the XML?

Comment: Because `getTag()` returns a generic `Object` (you can store anything as a tag if you do it in code). If you did this programatically you could do `view.setTag(Integer(1));` and then just do `(Integer)view.getTag()` later, but it's much more convenient in this instance to just do it in XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force an ID to a specific value. There is no way to do it in Android, the Android Asset Packaging Tool (AAPT) will always automatically generate them for you.

But you can still hide the "ugly" conversion from constant to integer in a function. example: `keyboardIdToFrequency()`

Answer (score 0):

you can add the specific value as Tag by using

```
btn.setTag("something");
```

and use in onTouch

```
Button btn = (Button)view;

String val = btn.Gettag();
note = Integer.Valueof(val)+ transposeOctave;
```